# RDBMS when field value depends on the row below it

Tags: mysql, database, rdbms

I need to port my company's excel records into a database.
There's a few columns that goes like this

```
A   B   C
a   b   edcb
a   c   edc
a   d   ed
a   e   e
b   f   gf
b   g   g
c   h   h
d   i   i
```

Column A and Column B are raw inputs, while Column C has a formula like `=IF(A2=A3, C3&B2, B2)`. 
The data is sorted by Column A. How can i go about structuring this in a MySQL database?

Comment: It looks like you gave an Excel formula, but you'd need more information for that to be meaningful in the context of MySQL.  You should update and show us more table data, and the expected output, along with any query you have tried.

Comment: The expected output is simply the same data displayed by the excel after a `SELECT * FROM` query.

Comment: The statement `A2 = A3` is meaningless in SQL without another column used to generate the order.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Add an auto-incrementing column? In the excel data, Col1 is manually sorted.

Comment: Ideally, you would have some way to identify two records as belonging to a pair.  This would be a start.

Comment: Please post some more sample data. We can reach nowhere with just 2 records. BTW your table structure is too bad. It does not make sense to store the calculated result in the same table from another column.

Comment: Ok added more sample data. "store the calculated result in the same table from another column" I thought the column can be stored in the same table as long as it is dependent on the primary keys? (in this case, col A&B would be the composite primary key)

Comment: Its better now, But I must say quite a weird requirement.

Comment: You can add the columns. I am not denying that. The thing is you can just generate the 3rd col by using a select statement.

Comment: Yes it is, but questioning the requirement is beyond my job scope and power. Preferably the 3rd col should be stored in the database instead of computing on the fly for better query performance.

Comment: You are not clear. You give a table here--ok then, have an SQL table that looks like that. What is your question? Please read and act on [mcve]. (You *appear* to be planning a *process*.) Please do not clarify in comments, edit your question. PS Tables have no order. Query "result sets" are ordered. Read about "window functions" for querying based on ordering during querying.

Comment: I guess you are trying to say that in some unspecified spreadsheet product "Column C has a formula like =IF(A2=A3, C3&B2, B2)" *for row 2*? And that cell Ci has value IF(Ai=Ai+1, Ci+1&Bi, Bi)? (Except that that formula alone doesn't work for the last row.) Since a row's C is a function of the table that is just columns A & B, the latter is all you need to store. @AnkitBajpai The projection on AB prefix-compresses & indexes/orders the (redundant) strings in C. Anyway, it's not clear what you are trying to ask.